# Creating linear model from training and test set

Tags: r

I have a dataset which I have first shuffled and then partitioned (k-fold) into a data frame which is the training set (67 observations) and a dataframe representing the test set (10 observations).

How would I go about making a linear model in R using the training set to predict the test set. And to get the accuracy or the error rate?

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier to answer if you show what your data looks like. Also, this sort of question can easiliy be answered by searching online.

To get a linear model, linear regression is the way to go. Use

```
model <- lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = trainData)
```

to get a linear model (assuming the variable you want to predict is called y and your predictive variables are x1 and x2). To predict your test data, use:

```
 predict(model, testData)
```

How to get accuracies depends whether you're doing regression or classification... For regression, you can use the result of predict and the vector of correct labels to calculate the RMSE for example. For classification, you can use `table()` and `classAgreement()`. Read more about them in the R documentation (with `?table()` for example).

I would advice you to read more about linear regression in R before you start! For example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/linear-regression-using-r/